# hive partitioning and bucketing

Tags: file, hive

I'm new on hive and wanted to bucket table  from a flat table.
My flat table is as follow

```
create table data(auth string, file string, documents string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t' ;
```

my bucket table is as follows

```
create table test(auth string, documents string)
partitioned by (file string)
clustered by(auth) into 2 buckets ;
```

I have to author A and B and their 10-10 documents,
 when I'm trying to insert data in bucketed table is executes successfully but the problem is that want all 10 files of each author in same partition but I'm getting one file with all 10 files content.

Comment: that is i m getting two different files for A and B and each file contains all their 10 files contents with respect to author. i want 10 files of A and 10 files of B in their author partitions

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the following Table structure:
flattable:

```
CREATE TABLE flattable (id INT, author STRING, book STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

bucketedtable:

```
CREATE TABLE bucketedtable (id INT, book STRING)
partitioned by (author STRING)
CLUSTERED BY (book) INTO 10 BUCKETS;
```

Set Properties in Hive:

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true; 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Insertion into bucketedtable from flammable

```
INSERT INTO TABLE bucketedtable
PARTITION (author)
SELECT  id, book, author
FROM flattable;
```

> You just need to swap the partitioned by and clustered by fields.